Summer school on real-world crypto and privacy, 5 - 10 june 2016
This summer school is jointly organized by the Digital Security (DS) group, Radboud University, The Netherlands, Faculty of Electrical Engineering and Computing, University of Zagreb, Croatia, the COSIC group, KU Leuven, Belgium, and ETH Zurich Information Security and Privacy Center, Switzerland.
It will take place in Šibenik (Croatia), June 5–10, 2016.
The school aims at bringing together PhD students, postdoc researchers and security experts from industry.

Secure hardware and physical security
Cryptography for the Internet
Formal methods in cryptography
Wireless security
Crypto for systems security
Privacy enhancing technologies
Traffic analysis and countermeasures
Recent developments in symmetric-key crypto

Website : http://summerschool-croatia.cs.ru.nl/2016/








I merged it with the "Community Promotion Ads - 2016" as that’s practically where it belongs.
